# How to return a list of tables that were used from a linker server database in my Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

In my DB, we have all Stored Procedures that selecting data from tables of linked server database.

For example:  the **Employee** table in our **SP_Employee** Stored Procedure in our server is extracting data from:
*select * from [LinkedServer].[IBM].[dbo].[**Employee**] em left join [LinkedServer].[IBM].[dbo].[**HR**] hr on em.ID=hr.ID.*

So right now, if i just want to get a list of those 2 linked server table names:  '**Employee**' &' **HR**' from my Stored Procedure, how to do that? write a script or cursor to extract those 2 names from my **SP_Employee**?
thanks

Comment: You want to find dependencies - if you search on that term you should find many examples. The short answer is yes - parse the code. One approach is [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127613/how-can-i-tell-what-database-procedure-is-using-a-linked-server).

Comment: thanks for your help